# Help me understand this lesson on implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm interested in becoming more fluent in Java so I have been going through [Sun/Oracle's java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html).  I'm on the section of implementing interfaces and I do not understand the code they have given as a solution to one of the exercises.

The [exercise](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/QandE/interfaces-questions.html) was to implement the java.lang.CharSequence interface, the implementation should return the string backwards, and to write a small main method to test your class; make sure to call all four methods.

This was a a little overwhelming so I began to work through their solution to see if I could understand the concepts and their code.  Here are my questions:

1) When they implement the `charAt` method, the are returning an invocation of the `charAt` method, why doesn't this cause some sort of infinite loop?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
/* Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. */
// CharSequenceDemo presents a String value -- backwards.
public class CharSequenceDemo implements CharSequence {
    private String s;

    public CharSequenceDemo(String s) {
        //It would be much more efficient to just reverse the string
        //in the constructor. But a lot less fun!
        this.s = s;
    }

    //If the string is backwards, the end is the beginning!
    private int fromEnd(int i) {
        return s.length() - 1 - i;
    }

    public char charAt(int i) {
        if ((i < 0) || (i >= s.length())) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(i);
        }
        return s.charAt(fromEnd(i));
    }

    public int length() {
        return s.length();
    }

    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        if (start < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
        }
        if (end > s.length()) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(end);
        }
        if (start > end) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start - end);
        }
        StringBuilder sub = 
        new StringBuilder(s.subSequence(fromEnd(end), fromEnd(start)));
        return sub.reverse();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.s);
        return s.reverse().toString();
    }

    //Random int from 0 to max.
    private static int random(int max) {
        return (int) Math.round(Math.random() * max + 0.5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSequenceDemo s =
        new CharSequenceDemo("Write a class that implements the CharSequence interface found in the java.lang package.");

        //exercise charAt() and length()
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        }

        //exercise subSequence() and length();
        int start = random(s.length() - 1);
        int end = random(s.length() - 1 - start) + start;
        System.out.println(s.subSequence(start, end));

        //exercise toString();
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) When they implement the charAt
>   method, the are returning an
>   invocation of the charAt method, why
>   doesn't this cause some sort of
>   infinite loop?

There's no infinite loop because the methods refer to two entirely different objects.

The interface defines the `charAt()` signature for a CharSequence.  The implementation in this case has a backing String instance.  The implementation for the CharSequence calls the `charAt()` method for the backing String instance.  No infinite loop, because it's not calling `this.charAt()`.

Comment: So the `s.charAt(fromEnd(i))` is actually calling the `charAt` method from java.lang.String because `s` is a String object?

Answer (score 3):

The nested call to charAt is to *s.charAt* which means you are invoking the same method but on *another* object.  No infinite loop there.

Their fromEnd is defined as

```
  private int fromEnd(int i) {
        return s.length() - 1 - i;
    }
```

almost at the top.

Comment: If I changed the variable name from this: `CharSequenceDemo s = new CharSequenceDemo("Write a class that implements the CharSequence interface found in the java.lang package.");` to this `CharSequenceDemo varString = new CharSequenceDemo("Write a class that implements the CharSequence interface found in the java.lang package.");` I would only need to change what is contained within my main method correct?  I think maybe because they have `s` used twice its confusing me, or am I off base?

Comment: `s.charAt()` is calling the String objects `charAt()`, not the same method as you claim.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `charAt` is not actually recursive, it is calling the `charAt` method of the `String` class for `String s`.
2. `fromEnd(i)` is a method call to the `fromEnd(int i)` method that is also defined in your class

-

```
//If the string is backwards, the end is the beginning!
    private int fromEnd(int i) {
        return s.length() - 1 - i;
    }
```